# Getting error when importing Facebook Upcoming events webcal to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, facebook-events

I'm trying to import Facebook's upcoming events ics file into Google Calendar and getting the following error:

> Settings Error
>   We could not parse the calendar at the url requested

Importing to Office365 was successful.

I validated the file with https://icalendar.org/validator.html#results - found only warnings. No errors.

Any idea why FB events can't be imported to Google Calendar?